# Custom Checkbox list control Error in asp.net. "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I am creating a custom checkbox control to add a div after each checkbox in a checkboxlist.
The class is below.

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class MyCheckboxListCheckBox
    Inherits CheckBoxList
    Implements IRepeatInfoUser
    Protected Overrides Sub RenderItem(ByVal itemType As ListItemType, ByVal repeatIndex As Integer, ByVal repeatInfo As RepeatInfo, ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)

        writer.WriteBeginTag("input")
        writer.WriteAttribute("type", "checkbox")
        writer.WriteAttribute("name", UniqueID)
        writer.WriteAttribute("id", (ClientID & "_") + repeatIndex.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo))
        writer.WriteAttribute("value", Items(repeatIndex).Value)
        Dim attrs As System.Web.UI.AttributeCollection = Items(repeatIndex).Attributes
        For Each key As String In attrs.Keys
            writer.WriteAttribute(key, attrs(key))
        Next
        writer.Write(">")

        writer.Write(Items(repeatIndex).Text)
        ' writer.Write("<div id=" & "mynewDiv" & Items(repeatIndex).Value & "></div>")


    End Sub



End Class
```

But I get an error when i use it in a page and call the save. The error is :

> startIndex cannot be larger than
>   length of string. Parameter name:
>   startIndex  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   startIndex cannot be larger than
>   length of string. Parameter name:
>   startIndex
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   startIndex cannot be larger than
>   length of string. Parameter name:
>   startIndex]
>   System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32
>   startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean
>   fAlwaysCopy) +7492915
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection
>   postCollection) +60
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection
>   postCollection) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection
>   postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +346
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1743

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have found the solution

I changed the name to be  " writer.WriteAttribute("name", UniqueID & "$" & repeatIndex)"

http://www.jasonlinham.co.uk/2009/04/checkboxlist-startindex-cannot-be.html
Thanks to Jason Linham's blog.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint on your overrides renderItem function declaration.  Start your project using VS debugging mode and trace what variables are set and to what.  I have a feeling that you are using a startindex of 1 on an empty string somewhere.  Remember, arrays and such start at 0.